# Factory method for generic class

Tags: typescript

I am trying to type a factory method in my class with the right return value. I've found plenty of questions about how to get the right type as I do in `f2` but In my case I use generics and I cannot get the right default type `B<string>`.

How can I get something like in `f3`???

```
class A<T> {
  static f1() {
    return new this()
  }

  static f2<Q>(this: { new (): Q }): Q {
    return new this()
  }
}

class B<K = string> extends A<K> {
  //
}

let x = new B()
let y = B.f1() // y: A<unknown>
let z = B.f2() // z: B<unknown>

let want = B.f3() // want: B<string>
```

Comment: What's the signature of `B.f3`?

Comment: That is the question. How to rewrite f2 to get the type in the comment

Comment: OK, well this works: `B<K = string> extends A<K> { static f3() {
    return new this();
  } }` but, if you don't mind my saying so, The way you are using generics seems really awkward to me. Maybe you can include more context so a cleaner pattern can be suggested. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECCA8AVAfNA3gWAFDWhALmPgJbDQBmAjABQCU62uuATgKb4CuzAdtN6wHdo+ABbEIdANyNoAX2wyCRUhQBM8AIrJqo8QC50fQdDoGNc2mYY4mbTjyNDdE2tJvysH7KEgwAQvAA0tAAvHj4zMTcAOaorAAe+KzcACYwCIGomDZKJGTkAMx01kzQdly8-E5iLm64Hh4g7NDxoY7QflLYTfjQAJ5tfgB0VF1YPdAAXoMjqmPdzQJg3L1hw4VS0AD0W9AiYABurAYBBJExyNhAA

Comment: that extends B and the question was about defining the factory method in the base class. The example in the question is taken from a larger use case in my code. I define a kind of facade on top of each Mongo Collection and the template is for the type of its documents.